# Minimum value of $p^2+q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, contest-math, quadratics

> Let $p$ and $q$ be real numbers such that $p^2+q>q^2+p$. Then the minimum value of $p^2+q$ is what?

My argument is as follows:

> Since $p,q$ are real numbers, it should not matter if we take $p$ as $x$ and $q$ as $y$.
> \begin{align*} p^2+q &> q^2+p \\ x^2-y^2 &> x-y \\ (x-y)(x+y-1)&>0\end{align*}
> So, we have to maximize $x^2+y$ subject to the conditions that:
> $$x-y>0,\quad x+y-1>0$$ or $$x-y<0,\quad x+y-1<0$$
> From the graph of thse, it's clear that the minimum value occurs at $(1/2,1/2)$ in region $1$ (labeled on the graph). So, $p^2+q = (1/2)^2+(1/2) = 3/4$.

[image]

However this is not the correct answer.
Can anyone suggest where I'm making a mistake?

Comment: If you let $p = q$, then we have that $p^2+q\not > q^2+p$.  So, choosing $p = q= \frac{1}{2}$ shouldn't work.

Comment: We have to minimise not maximise $x^2+y $.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this function can't be minimized on this domain since the domain is open and the function's gradient is never $0$. It can get arbitrarily close to $-1/4$, however, if $p=-1/2$ and $q>-1/2$ is close.

Comment: @navinstudent In your formulation a minimum does not exist. See my solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $p\in \mathbb{R}$, we find the set of $q\in\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $p^2+q>q^2-p$. Rewrite the inequality:

$$q^2-q-(p^2+p)<0$$

The roots of $q^2-q-(p^2+p)=0$ are

$$q=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1+4\left(p^2+p\right)}}{2}$$

Notice that $4p^2+4p+1={(2p+1)}^2$, and hence the roots are $p$ and $p+1$.
Thus, $q \in (p,p+1)$.

For any fixed $p$, the task of minimizing $p^2+q$ therefore reduces to minimizing $q\in(p,p+1)$. We see the infimum is $p^2+p$, but there is no actual minimum.

Finally, letting $p$ (and thus $q$) vary throughout $\mathbb{R}$, the minimum of $p^2+p$ can be easily found to be $p=-\frac12$. Any methods for min-maxing a quadratic equation will do.

Comment: Indeed, a minimum of $p^2+p$ occurs for $p=-\frac{1}{2}$, but it does not give any relation to our problem. I think, it's nothing!

Comment: For each $p$, the infimum of $p^2+q$ where $q$ satisfies $p^2+q>q^2+p$ equals $p^2+p$. Hence, the infimum of $p^2+q$ equals the infimum of $p^2+p$. This infimum is never properly attained though.

Comment: We see it In retrospect. You need to prove it!

Answer (score 3):

I'll solve the following problem.

Let $p^2+q\geq q^2+p$. Find a minimal value of $p^2+q$.

Indeed, $p^2+q+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(p+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(q+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2\right)+\frac{1}{2}(p^2+q-q^2-p)\geq0$.

The equality occurs for $p=q=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Id est, the answer is $-\frac{1}{4}$.

Answer (score 1):

From what is given;
$p^2+q \ge \frac{1}{2}(p^2+q+q^2+p) \ge \frac{-1}{4}$

The last step obviously can easily be explained using quadratic formula, AM-GM etc. or whatever you like.

Answer (score 0):

Solving the problem with the following condition $p^2+q>=q^2+p$, since minimum won't exist for open set. Fist of all its clear that minimum won't lie in the region 1. Second the gradient of $x^2+y$ is $(2x,1)$ which will never vanish, which means that the minimum can not lie inside the region because you can always decrease y to get a better solution. So minimum can only lie on the boundaries, now it won't lie on $x+y=1$, as you can improve the solution by taking corresponding point on $x=y$(by corresponding I mean reflection through $y=1/2)$. So It can only lie on $x=y$, so what we have to do is find minimum of $x^2+x$, which will occur at $x=-1/2$. So the answer is -1/4

Answer (score -4):

It appears that you made an error early on in your proof. You got (x-y)(x+y-1)>0 when you should've gotten x+y-1>0, as the x-y terms cancel each other out.

Comment: He subtracted $x-y$ from both sides of the inequality.

Comment: But you don't subtract; you should be dividing.

Comment: Why? In principle, you don't even know if $x-y>0$. The sign of the inequality might change.